# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLProgressElement': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to install the existing jquery component (progress-bar for reading) but it doesn't work. I don't know jquery, help me please:

HTML:

```
<progress value="0">
<div class="progress-container">
  <span class="progress-bar"></span>
</div>
</progress>
```

JS:

```
    $(function () {
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        var o = $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
        $(".progress-bar").css({
            "width": (100 * o | 0) + "%"
        });
        $('progress')[0].value = o;
    })  
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ok so, after you showed me the page with its css, I saw that the actual problem was there, in the css. Set `height: 100%;` on the `section` node and the original code you posted will work.

Original answer:

You are dividing 0 by something when scrollTop() returns 0, and something by 0 when `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` returns 0. The result is `NaN` in the first case and `Infinity` in the second case. Try this code:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var heightDiff = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
        var o = top == 0 ? 0 : (top / (heightDiff == 0 ? 1 : heightDiff));
        $(".progress-bar").css({
            "width": (100 * o) + "%"
        });
        $('progress')[0].value = o;
    })  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now i dont see errors, but script works uncorrect :( There is correct example: http://хранилище.кодер.укр/posts/demo/progress/index.html

Comment: I edited the answer, the problem was in the css. I couldn't know without seeing your actual html with the css.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my breakpoints were custom, and the library had base breakpoints. So, all I had to do was adding base breakpoints to my custom ones and set them to false

```
const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({
  values: {
    xs: false,
    sm: false,
    md: false,
    lg: false,
    xl: false,
    bp_320: 0,
    bp_414: 414,
    bp_768: 768,
    bp_1024: 1024,
    bp_1280: 1280,
    bp_1366: 1366,
    bp_1600: 1600,
    bp_1900: 1900,
  },
});
```

the error disappeared, and the project is working again